# cacheAsBitmap forces MovieClip to vanish

Tags: bitmap, haxe, antialiasing, openfl

I'm trying to get antialiasing on a MovieClip object after constructing it from a object and its mask, both MovieClips loaded from swf via SWFLite:

```
var icon:MovieClip = Assets.getBattleAbility(ability.id); //getting a base object
icon = squareToRound(icon); // applying a mask (new MovieClip-container created)
add(icon, treeAbX(ability.j), treeAbY(ability.i));
icon.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

The object doesn't appear. When I added a click listener to a object with handler setting cacheAsBitmap to true, object began to vanish after I clicked on it.

What could be the problem here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a [known issue](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues/1687) with mask positioning when `cacheAsBitmap = true`.

Comment: Seems like that issue is abandoned, at least for now, so I wonder if there is any ways to work around.

I'm making a game, it has 6+ strains each consisting of 28 abilities. Each of the abilities has a square icon that is used in battle and a similar round icon that is used between battles. I decided to use round mask not to double the work I do when I draw these icons, but without anti-aliasing, round icons look way too angular.

Comment: The linked issue appears to work using current development versions of OpenFL and Lime. If there is still an issue, a small test case would be valuable for reproducing the issue. Thank you! :)